# Fitting customized LGBM parameters in sklearn pipeline

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, lightgbm

I am working on a binary classifier using LightGBM. My classifier definition looks like following:

```py
# sklearn version, for the sake of calibration
bst_ = LGBMClassifier(**search_params, **static_params, n_estimators = 1500)

bst_.fit(X = X_train, y = y_train, sample_weight = TRAIN_WEIGHTS,
         eval_set = (X_test, y_test), eval_sample_weight = [TEST_WEIGHTS],
         eval_metric = my_scorer,
         early_stopping_rounds = 150, 
         callbacks = [lgb.reset_parameter(learning_rate = lambda current_round: learning_rate_decay(current_round, 
                                                                                                    base_learning_rate = learning_rate,
                                                                                                    decay_power = decay_power))],
         categorical_feature = cat_vars)
```

where `**search_params` are hyperparameters optimized by Optuna and `**static_params` are predefined parameters such as `'objective'` or `'random_state'`.

On top of that I define weights on each of the target using `sample_weight`, I use customized objective function `my_scorer`, early stopping and decaying learning rate defined as below:

```py
def learning_rate_decay(current_iter, base_learning_rate = 0.05, decay_power = 0.99):
    lr = base_learning_rate  * np.power(decay_power, current_iter)
    return lr if lr > 1e-3 else 1e-3
```

As I want to have probabilities as a result of my modelling, I would like to use isotonic regression as a final part of the forecasting pipeline. I know that I could use following code:

```py
# Calibrate 
calibrated_clf = CalibratedClassifierCV(
    base_estimator=bst_,
    method = 'isotonic',
    cv="prefit"
)
calibrated_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

but according to [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html#calibrating-a-classifier), I shouldn't be using "prefit" on train dataset. I would like to create a pipeline, which would maintain all the arguments defined in my classifier `.fit` (such as callback), something like this:

```py
calibrated_clf = CalibratedClassifierCV(
    base_estimator=bst_,
    method='isotonic',
    cv=5
)
calibrated_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
calibrated_clf.set_params(**customized_lgbm_params)
```

yet obviously it doesn't work, as those are specific parameters for fitting the data to the model.

My question is: how could I define a pipeline which would include all the features of `LGBMClassifier.fit` that I have already defined (such as early stopping, applying weights, callbacks)?

Answer (score 0):

Use sklearn's pipeline

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ("classifier", CalibratedClassifier(
        base_estimator=bst_(**search_params),
        method='isotonic', 
        cv=5) 
    )
])
```

Comment: thanks, but it won't work - I need the arguments that can be used in the `.fit` function of the LGBMClassifier, such as callbacks. In your solution they won't be used.